# Can 2,025 cM shared indicate full Siblings?

Tags: autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

My brother and I did ancestry tests at different times. We had 2,025cM over 39 segments. Longest one was 158. As I looked at our matches all I could see was my moms side of the family. It was saying he is in the close family group.

Is a full sibling still possible?

Answer (score 3):

[DNAPainter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/2025) suggests that there's a 4% chance (based on 2025cM) that you are full siblings.  So not impossible, but not likely either.

Other possible relationships: Grandparent, Aunt/Uncle, Half Sibling, Niece/Nephew, Grandchild

I suspect that you can eliminate several of those ;-)

If all your shared matches are on one side of the family, that's a big hint, too.